# Update table starting from today's date in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, pivot-table

I have an excel worksheet similar to the following -

- Col A - Clients name,
- Col B - Col D - Cient's info such as address, Phone no etc and
- Col E - Date of next meeting.

I want to create a table such that

- Col A will be Date of Next meeting,
- Col B will be Clients name,
- Col C - Col E will be Clients info.

The condition is that everytime I open the table it will start from 'today' or the closest date (next future date in the list) as in Col A with the Date of next meeting and the table holds data for the next 30 days. Any idea how to move forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the source table by the Date of next meeting.

Then for the first column of your table, you may refer to the following array formula and drag down to fill the rest(Remember to press **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** to make it an array formula. You may need to adjust the data range D2:D9 according to your data source.):

```
=TEXT(INDEX(E:E,SMALL(IF(($E$2:$E$9>=TODAY())*($E$2:$E$9<TODAY()+30),ROW($E$2:$E$9),4^8),ROW(E1)))&"","[>0]m/d/yyyy;")
```

[image]
For the other three columns, use the array formula below(Press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to make it an array formula. Adjust the data range if necessary.):

```
=INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(($E$2:$E$9>=TODAY())*($E$2:$E$9<TODAY()+30),ROW($E$2:$E$9),4^8),ROW(E1)))&""
```

Drag down and right to fill the table.
[image]

If you would like to do it in a separate sheet, for example, the original data is in Sheet1 and you want to create the new table in Sheet2, just modify the data range in the formulas, and press **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** to make it an array formula:

```
=TEXT(INDEX(Sheet1!E:E,SMALL(IF((Sheet1!$E$2:$E$9>=TODAY())*(Sheet1!$E$2:$E$9<TODAY()+30),ROW($E$2:$E$9),4^8),ROW(Sheet2!E1)))&"","[>0]m/d/yyyy;")
```

[image]

=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,SMALL(IF((Sheet1!$E$2:$E$9>=TODAY())*(Sheet1!$E$2:$E$9[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton Yuki. Can we do it in a separate worksheet too?

Comment: Did you try the formula? It shows error though!

Comment: Yes, we can do it in a separate worksheet, but you need to change the data range in the formula.

Comment: Thanks Yuki. I am new in Excel. Can you please tell me how can I add entire column instead of  D2:D9 in the formula? Since my list of Clients name will increase over time, how can I select the entire column so that the formula applies to all the cells of D containing data.?

Comment: You can change 9 to a large enough number, like 100000.

Comment: Thanks. What about 4^8? How can I write that part?

Comment: 4^8 refers to the maximum rows(65536) in lower versions of Excel. If you are using Excel newer than 2007 and your data source contains more rows, you can change it to larger number such as 2^20, which means the largest row number in Excel 2007 and above.